# How to move columns without compressed text in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to move the margin of column, but after that my text is compressed.on this paragraph `<p>James plays tug-o-war on the beach with Jasmine.</p>` for the following HTML:

```html
<div class="row5">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
    <h2> WELCOME </h2>
    <p class="p1"> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley. </p>
    <p class="p2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
    <h2>ABOUT</h2>

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="img/avatar.png" alt="" class="img-responsive pull-right">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p>James plays tug-o-war on the beach with Jasmine.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- End row 5 -->
```

I tried this, but after that text is compressed.

```css
.row5 .row{
  margin-right: 5em;
}
```

I want to move jointly two columns, but without text compressed. You know from the code, first column is a picture, second is text.

Comment: Is [this illustration](http://i.imgur.com/LJ8xUsW.png) idenntify the issue.  I'm having trouble seeing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here is illustration which you want to see http://i.imgur.com/nwEAoyM.png

Comment: can you add what you want it to look like?  what are you trying to accomplish with margin-right?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/fDhuk4k.png
Upper image is what it looks like now.
Lower image is what i want to do.
I want to move jointly little thumbnail and text, but when i move my text is compressed liked this on right image http://i.imgur.com/nwEAoyM.png
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is shift the entire row the left by `5em`.  That's not precisely what `margin-right: 5em;` does.  Margin-right will reduce the entire size of the `.row`. The columns will then take up 50% of a smaller available area.

To do what you're trying to do, you can use the `translateX` transform like this:

```css
.myRow {
  transform: translateX(-5em);
}
```

Example

[image: Example]

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```css
.myRow {
  transform: translateX(-5em);
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row5">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-7 col-xs-12">
    <h2> WELCOME </h2>
    <p class="p1"> Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley. </p>
    <p class="p2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
    <h2>ABOUT</h2>

    <div class="row myRow">

      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/6KUnmtF.png" alt="" class="img-responsive pull-right">
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <p>James plays tug-o-war on the beach with Jasmine.</p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- End row 5 -->
```

2D transforms will [work on almost all browsers except ie8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: sorry if i break rules, but I want to ask you something, in this case when i set for the second column in this case of p tag column, when i set col-xs-3 for first column(thumbnail column) and col-xs-9 (text column).
It does the same to me as your code with translate ....
i think you understand me

Comment: @IgorSimic, You could do that too if you want

Answer (score 0):

HTML Elements take as much space as they are adviced to take, if they have no advice on how much space to take, div-Elements will spread out. In your case you're using col-xs-6 which makes your p Element and the container it's in float. Now you're giving the row which contains those 2 a margin-right of 5em, but the col-xs-6 sizes stay the same. So if you'd want to move the second column, you'd have to act on that one.

By the way, you only want to act on your p, so why not give the container a class?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 makeSpace">
   <p>James plays tug-o-war on the beach with Jasmine.</p>
</div>
```

Now you can define things like:

```
.makeSpace {
  margin-right: 5em;
}
```

But remember (!) that col-xs-6 might already define such a margin.

Comment: Thank you dear man, but i don't understand what I have to do.

I put makeSpace in HTML and in CSS, but not working.You sad "that col-xs-6 might already define such a margin." I dont understand this, I don't know what i have to do.